# reading a password from local file and passing in pyspark script

Tags: python, shell

i am trying to read the password from file and passing into SAP connection. Since i have 50+ scripts using same password, where if password gets chnaged i no need to go in each script and change instead i can simply change in one file.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false")

ZTGLINT011_query = """ (select * from ZTGLINT011) a """

#passwd = sc.textFile("file:///root/Documents/pwd.txt")

passwd=cat /root/Documents/pwd.txt

ZTGLINT011 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sap://myIP:30015",currentschema="SAPABAP1",user="loginName",password=passwd,dbtable=ZTGLINT011_query).load()

ZTGLINT011.write.format("parquet").save("/user/admin/sqoop/base/sap/ZTGLINT011/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in txt file enter content:

{
"Password":"your password"
}

Copy paste you code this will work:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false")

ZTGLINT011_query = """ (select * from ZTGLINT011) a """

passwfile = open("/root/Documents/pwd.txt", "r")
contents = passwfile.read()
info = json.dumps(contents)

passwd = info['Password']

ZTGLINT011 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sap://myIP:30015",currentschema="SAPABAP1",user="loginName",password=passwd,dbtable=ZTGLINT011_query).load()    
    ZTGLINT011.write.format("parquet").save("/user/admin/sqoop/base/sap/ZTGLINT011/")
```

Comment: If this is helpful can you please mark it helpful or vote for it thanks.

Comment: i used this code in daily job script..but y'day it failed saying ```` Stdoutput     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ````

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false")

ZTGLINT011_query = """ (select * from ZTGLINT011) a """

passwfile = open("/root/Documents/pwd.txt", "r")

for passwd in passwfile:
    ZTGLINT011 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sap://myIP:30015",currentschema="SAPABAP1",user="loginName",password=passwd,dbtable=ZTGLINT011_query).load()    
    ZTGLINT011.write.format("parquet").save("/user/admin/sqoop/base/sap/ZTGLINT011/")
```

Comment: it says  Stdoutput NameError: name 'cat' is not defined . can you write down the syntex .i am new into shell.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to store the password, Username, IP, PORT etc you file /root/Documents/pwd.txt as

============pwd.txt : contents ============

{
    "IP": "myIP",
    "PORT": 8080,
    "Usernme": "user",
    "Password": "pass"
}

===============================================

In your code :

```
import json
f= open('/root/Documents/pwd.txt','r')
contents = f.read()
server_details = json.loads(contents)
password = server_details['Password']
username=server_details['Password']
Port =server_details["PORT"]
IP=server_details["IP"]

ZTGLINT011 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:sap://"+IP+":"+Port,currentschema="SAPABAP1",user=username,password=password,dbtable=ZTGLINT011_query).load()
```

you can add currentschema and dbtable also in the txt file

Comment: Thanks Shrikant.. i have just passed the password in pwd.txt file.. getting below error. `Stdoutput     raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
Stdoutput ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded `